# how to check if a string contains only lower case letters and numbers?

Tags: python

How can I check if a string contains **only** numbers and lower case letters?

I only managed to check if it contains numbers and lower case letters and doesn't contain upper case letters but I don't know how to check that it doesn't contain any symbols as ^&*(% etc..

```
if(any(i.islower() for i in password) and any(i.isdigit() for i in password) and not any(i.isupper() for i in password)):
```

EDIT:
so apparently I need to do this without using any loops and mainly using functions like .islower() , .isdigit() , isalnum() etc.. and I have no idea how I can check if a string contains lower case letters and numbers only , without using loops or something that will check every single char in the string . we only started to learn the basics in python so they told us we can't use "for" and all that even if I know what it does.. now I can check if an entire string is only digits or lower/upper case letters but I don't know how to check the two conditions mentioned above in the simplest way possible

Comment: You are looking for the re module.  It allows regex checking.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
if all(c.isdigit() or c.islower() for c in password):
```

after all, you want to check that **all** characters are either a digit or lowercase letters. So for all characters `c`, that character is `c.isdigit() or c.islower()`. Now an `all(..)` takes as input an *iterable* of values and checks if the *truthiness* of all these values is `True`. So from the moment there is one digit that does not satisfies our condition, the `all(..)` will return `False`.

Mind however that **`all(..)` is `True` if there are no elements**. Indeed if the `password` is the empty string, **all** the characters satisfy this condition, since there are no characters.

**EDIT**:

In case you want to check that the `password` contains both digits and lowercase characters, you can alter the condition to:

```
if all(c.isdigit() or c.islower() for c in password) and \
       any(c.isdigit() for c in password) and \
       any(c.islower() for c in password):
```

Now the check will only succeed if there are *at least* two characters in `password`: a lower and a digit.

Comment: but I need to make sure the string contains both numbers and lower case letters . and if i'll use this condition - it will return true if the string contains lower case letters only or if the string contains numbers only.. and I need it to return true when the string contains lower case letters and numbers only

Comment: If part of your answer is incorrect, don't just add a correct version below an "EDIT". Remove the incorrect part, it's useless.

Comment: @BryanOakley: well the `all(..)` part is the answer to how enforce that the password only contains lowers and digits :). Which is the added value. The edit was more to show how to incorporate that answer into the code, since that was apparently unclear :).

Comment: Ok, my mistake.

Comment: so apparently I need to do this without using any loops and mainly using functions like .islower() , .isdigit() , isalnum() etc.. and I have no idea how I can check if a string contains lower case letters and numbers only , without using loops or something that will check every single char in the string . we only started to learn the basics in python so they told us we can't use "for" and all that even if I know what it does.. no I can check an entire string is only digits or lower/upper case letters but I don't know how to check the two conditions mentioned above in the simplest way possible

Answer (score 6):

How about use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> def is_digit_and_lowercase_only(s):
        return re.match("^[\da-z]+$", s)
>>> print is_digit_and_lowercase_only("dA")
None
>>> print is_digit_and_lowercase_only("adc87d6f543sc")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x107c46988>
```

It'll return `None` if match failed, so you can use it with `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to count the letters of each type and make sure they're not zero (in this context True equates to 1 and False to 0):

```
def validate_password(password):
    """
    Return True if password contains digits and lowercase letters
    but nothing else and is at least 8 characters long; otherwise
    return False.

    """

    ndigits = sum(c.isdigit() for c in password)
    nlower = sum(c.islower() for c in password)
    password_length = len(password)
    return (password_length > 7 and ndigits and nlower and
            (ndigits+nlower)==password_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that applies your rules using sets for membership testing .

```
import string
lower = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
digits = set(string.digits)
def valid(s):
    '''Test string for valid characters, and composition'''

    s = set(s)
    invalid = s.difference(lower, digits)
    both = s.intersection(lower) and s.intersection(digits)
    return bool(both and not invalid)
```

Usage:

```
>>> valid('12234')
False
>>> valid('abcde')
False
>>> valid('A123')
False
>>> valid('a$1')
False
>>> valid('1a')
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest answer from the top of my head:

```
if str1 == str1.lower():
    # string is only lower case
else:
    # string is not only lower case
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isdigit() or islower() method to check string contains only numbers and lower case letters

```
import string
input_str=raw_input()


for ch in input_str:

    if  ch.isdigit() or  ch.islower():
        output_str=True

    else:
        output_str=False
        break   

print output_str
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [87]: '123anydigitorletterorevenunicodeßßидажелатиница'.isalnum()
Out[87]: True

In [88]: '123anydigitorletterorevenunicodeßßидажелатиница'.islower()
Out[88]: True
```

So the solution is

```
if password.islower() and password.isalnum():
    ...some code...
```

I can not figure out what for to iterate the string